# What is the standard way to install jdk for wildfly on production?

Tags: java, deployment, sysadmin, devops

There are options like, install from repo, install from rpm and install from tar/zip/etc archive
What are the pros and cons?

One con of installing from archive is, you don't get security updates. Is there any important advantage of installing from archive (as in, just unzip to a folder of your choice and point the path/java home)?
In case of installing from rpm/repo is there any danger that a java update breaks an app? For example, the nginx update overwrites the index.html file. In case of java, would it similarly step on something that is customized, or introduce some incompatibility with existing code? Sorry I am new to this side of java so please bear with me.

This is in the context of production deployment. Is there an accepted standard of doing this and if so what is it?

Assume I am using jdk 11 and wildfly